# How to put JsonObject in to ArrayList<>

Tags: arraylist, json

My input is json data. it looks like this:

```
[
    {
    "City": 2,
    "Dist": 214,
    "Desc": "Chung cư Ecolife Capitol là tổ hợp khu nhà ở, văn phòng và dịch vụ cao cấp nằm tại cửa ngõ phía Tây thủ đô Hà Nội với quy mô lên tới 10.622 m2. Với vị trí đắc địa, thiết kế không gian mở bố trí hài hòa với môi trường cảnh quan xung quanh tạo nên một không gian xanh – môi trường sống thư giãn lý tưởng cho nhiều hộ gia đình hiện đại.¦• Diện tích căn hộ đa dạng: 60, 72, 84, 97, 102, 115, 121, m2.¦• Giá bán căn hộ Ecolife Capitol chỉ 1,4 tỷ/căn đã bao gồm Vat + Full Nội thất.¦• Ngân hàng hỗ trợ tới 70% giá trị hợp đồng với lãi suất 7.5% năm đầu.¦• Chiết khấu hấp dẫn 3% giá trị căn hộ – Cơ hội đầu tư tuyệt vời.¦Mở Bán Chính Thức 760 Căn Hộ Tòa A1,A2 & A3 Chung Cư Ecolife Capitol Lê Văn Lương.¦Các căn hộ Ecolife Capiol đã bắt đầu được mở bán đợt 1 chính thức với mức giá hấp dẫn. Quý khách hàng quan tâm liên hệ sớm để lựa chọn được những căn tầng đẹp và phù hợp nhất:¦Hotline: 01629.685.865 – 0942.893.992.",
    "Area": 10622,
    "Price": 1400,
    "Title": "Mở Bán Chung cư Ecolife Capitol - 60 Lê Văn Lương",
    "RawArea": "10.622 m2",
    "RawPrice": "1,4 ty",
    "PubDate": "2015-10-09T15:05:52.79+07:00"
    }
]
```

How can I put json object data into array list < INFO > ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code, rather than adding it as comments, and give the code where you are attempting to do what you want, rather than just the class structure.

Comment: my Json Response look like on. EX : [ {"City":2  ,  "Dist":214  , "Desc" :"v.vv"...}]
 I create contructor using save result value , look on , It is class "infor"
 I want put json object in to ArrayList<info> . Help me! thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio

1. Install GSON Plugin on Android Studio

[image: Install GSON Plugin on Android Studio]

2. Create the POJO Class (simple java class)

   ```
   public class InfoModal {
   List<Info> info;

   public List<InfoModal.Info> getInfo() {
   if(info==null)
       info=new ArrayList<>();
   return info;
   }

   public void setInfo(InfoModal.Info infoTmp) {
   if(info==null)
       info=new ArrayList<>();
   this.info.add(infoTmp);
   }

   public class Info
   {
   private int City;
   private int Dist;
   private String Desc;
   private double Area;
   private double Price;
   private String Title;
   private String RawArea;
   private String RawPrice;
   private String PubDate;

   public void setCity(int City) {
       this.City = City;
   }

   public void setDist(int Dist) {
       this.Dist = Dist;
   }

   public void setDesc(String Desc) {
       this.Desc = Desc;
   }

   public void setArea(double Area) {
       this.Area = Area;
   }

   public void setPrice(double Price) {
       this.Price = Price;
   }

   public void setTitle(String Title) {
       this.Title = Title;
   }

   public void setRawArea(String RawArea) {
       this.RawArea = RawArea;
   }

   public void setRawPrice(String RawPrice) {
       this.RawPrice = RawPrice;
   }

   public void setPubDate(String PubDate) {
       this.PubDate = PubDate;
   }

   public int getCity() {
       return City;
   }

   public int getDist() {
       return Dist;
   }

   public String getDesc() {
       return Desc;
   }

   public double getArea() {
       return Area;
   }

   public double getPrice() {
       return Price;
   }

   public String getTitle() {
       return Title;
   }

   public String getRawArea() {
       return RawArea;
   }

   public String getRawPrice() {
       return RawPrice;
   }

   public String getPubDate() {
       return PubDate;
   }
   }
   }
   ```
3. Paste JSON to GSONFORMAT Wizard

[image]

4. Add GSON Dependency Gradle(2)

[image]

5. Serialise the JSON to POJO

   ```
   try
   {
       String response="[{\"City\":2,\"Dist\":214,\"Desc\":\"Chung cư Ecolife Capitol là tổ hợp khu nhà ở, văn phòng và dịch vụ cao cấp nằm tại cửa ngõ phía Tây thủ đô Hà Nội với quy mô lên tới 10.622 m2. Với vị trí đắc địa, thiết kế không gian mở bố trí hài hòa với môi trường cảnh quan xung quanh tạo nên một không gian xanh – môi trường sống thư giãn lý tưởng cho nhiều hộ gia đình hiện đại.¦• Diện tích căn hộ đa dạng: 60, 72, 84, 97, 102, 115, 121, m2.¦• Giá bán căn hộ Ecolife Capitol chỉ 1,4 tỷ/căn đã bao gồm Vat + Full Nội thất.¦• Ngân hàng hỗ trợ tới 70% giá trị hợp đồng với lãi suất 7.5% năm đầu.¦• Chiết khấu hấp dẫn 3% giá trị căn hộ – Cơ hội đầu tư tuyệt vời.¦Mở Bán Chính Thức 760 Căn Hộ Tòa A1,A2 & A3 Chung Cư Ecolife Capitol Lê Văn Lương.¦Các căn hộ Ecolife Capiol đã bắt đầu được mở bán đợt 1 chính thức với mức giá hấp dẫn. Quý khách hàng quan tâm liên hệ sớm để lựa chọn được những căn tầng đẹp và phù hợp nhất:¦Hotline: 01629.685.865 – 0942.893.992.\",\"Area\":10622.0,\"Price\":1400.0,\"Title\":\"Mở Bán Chung cư Ecolife Capitol - 60 Lê Văn Lương\",\"RawArea\":\"10.622 m2\",\"RawPrice\":\"1,4 ty\",\"PubDate\":\"2015-10-09T15:05:52.79+07:00\"}]";
       JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
       Gson gson=new Gson();
       InfoModal infoModal=new InfoModal();
       for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
       {
           JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
           InfoModal.Info info=gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), InfoModal.Info.class);
           Log.e("Log","Info = "+info.getTitle());
           infoModal.setInfo(info);
       }
       List<InfoModal.Info> infos=infoModal.getInfo();
   }
   catch (JSONException e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```